# Retrieving DHCP options in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, networking, dhcp

I would like to ask if there is a way to retrieve (query) [DHCP Option](http://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml#options) from DHCP in iOS (Swift/Objective-C)?

E.g. if I would like to retrieve IP address from DHCP Option 7 (Log Server), what should I do?

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Comment: @GusevAndrey Nope.